# Running a "piping" script from an os.system() command

Tags: python, pipe

I currently have a script ("monitor") which monitors and outputs various system-type data to the screen.  I have a Python program which is post processing that information when I use this command to pipe the monitor output to my Python program.

```
/usr/local/bin/monitor | /mnt/usbkey/pgms/myMonitorPgm.py
```

This much is working just fine.

I would like to use an os.system command (or something else??) to run the monitor script and create the pipe from within my Python program.  This would run when I start my Python program and thus eliminate the need the above piping format/command.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably look at the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module, in particular create a Popen object with stdout=PIPE then you can use communicate() or similar to read from the pipe within your Python program.

For example, you could do:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen( [ '/usr/local/bin/monitor' ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
stdout, _ = proc.communicate()
```

Now stdout will have the output from running the monitor program.

Comment: Eric...I tried the following:

`#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
tcpdmp = subprocess.Popen(["sudo tcpdump -A -n -p -l -i eth0 -s0 -w - tcp dst port 80"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, )`

and got this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/usbdrive/Pgms/TestPipe.py", line 6, in <module>
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks...RDK

Comment: The problem with what you tried is that if you aren't specifying shell=True in the Popen constructor you need to pass in a list (or tuple) where each element is an argument, so the first thing is the executable, then the rest of the elements of the list are the arguments, e.g., [ 'sudo', 'tcpdump', '-A', '-n', '-p', '-l', '-i', 'eth0', ...] and so forth

Comment: I'm running this on a Raspberry Pi and the script runs fine from the command prompt

Comment: Right, but the way subprocess invokes the command is what's at issue.  The first argument to subprocess.Popen is a list of arguments, not a string containing the command to run--unless you specify shell=True in the constructor then the first argument is a string passed to the shell to execute.

Comment: Thanks Eric.  That part of the program now seems to be working, or at least not throwing an error.  I will make another posting with a follow-up questions.  Thanks again.....RDK

Answer (score 0):

In my case what worked was:

```py
with open('/tmp/mailbody', 'w') as f:
    f.write(body)
os.system('/usr/bin/heirloom-mailx -s ' + subject + ' ' + mail + '< /tmp/mailbody')
```